# Babel7 Jest unexpected token export

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I am having issues in running jest tests in my project with Babel7. Tests used to transpile perfectly with babel6. It also compiles perfectly with webpack with Babel7 but fails to run tests with jest due to a transpilation error. What am I doing wrong?

```
react/node_modules/generic-redux-root/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './source/CreateReduxRoot';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

my jest config

```
{
"unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs",
  "enzyme"
],
"roots": [
  "<rootDir>/__tests__"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(^generic-)/i", //a module matching this is throwing an error
  "node_modules/react-infinite-scroller"
],
"setupFiles": [
  "./jestsetup.js"
],
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
],
"testResultsProcessor": "./jestTrxProcessor",
"verbose": true
```

}

My .babelrc

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "targets": {
                "ie": 11
            },
            "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
            "legacy": true
        }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
]
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps a useful [article for Babel 7 and Jest](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-testing-tutorial/) for anyone who is stumbling on this issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is happening because Babel 7 no longer loads your `.babelrc` automatically. 
There is a new concept of `root config` which should be located in the root of your project and the file must be named [`babel.config.js`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/config-files#project-wide-configuration) and export an object.

So to give you some steps to follow:

1. rename your `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and make sure you use `module.exports = {...}`
2. run `jest --clearCache` to clear Jest internal cache (which costed me a few hours of banging my head against the wall)
3. At this point your babel config should be loaded correctly by Jest

Comment: Thanks for your help! That seems to have solved this error but now I am facing another strange error. I've created a question for that https://stackoverflow.com/q/52400840/1032179

Comment: Cool! :) I'd been banging my head against the wall a few hours before I found this answer :)

Comment: also make sure you don't have `modules: false` set ;)

Comment: Wow. modules: false totally did it for us.

Comment: It took me a whole day to solve the problem.
**.babelrc** to **babel.config.js** works for me. 
Thanks, man.