# Babel 7 Jest Core JS "TypeError: wks is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest, babel-polyfill

After upgrading my project to Babel 7, running tests through Jest is throwing the following error. The tests used to run without any issues in Babel 6, but they are failing in Babel 7 with the following error

```
TypeError: wks is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (node_modules/core-js/modules/_fix-re-wks.js:16:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace.js:4:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.symbol.js:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/_is-object.js:5:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/_inherit-if-required.js:3:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor.js:5:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.regexp.match.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.function.name.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/_wks.js:3:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/_add-to-unscopables.js:4:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js:3:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable.js:3:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:3:1)
```

#### Jest configuration

```
{
"unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils",
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs",
  "enzyme"
],
"roots": [
  "<rootDir>/__tests__"
],
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(^generic-)/i", //a module matching this is throwing an error
  "node_modules/react-infinite-scroller"
],
"setupFiles": [
  "./jestsetup.js"
],
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
],
"testResultsProcessor": "./jestTrxProcessor",
"verbose": true
  }
```

#### File *babel.js.config*

```
{
"presets": [
    [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
            "targets": {
                "ie": 11
            },
            "useBuiltIns": "usage"
        }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
],
"plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {
            "legacy": true
        }
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign"
    ]
}
```

#### File *package.json*

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "create-if-not-exist": "^0.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint": "^4.13.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-defaults": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "generic-redux-root": "^0.0.1",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "jest-cli": "^23.4.1",
    "jest-trx-results-processor": "^0.0.7",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "es6-promise": "^3.3.1",
    "flux": "^3.1.3",
    "generic-api-fetch": "1.0.1",
    "generic-http": "^1.0.2",
    "generic-limited-textarea": "^1.1.0",
    "generic-select": "^1.0.3",
    "generic-throttled-select": "^1.0.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-addons-update": "15.6.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.1.3",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.6",
    "react-select": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.4"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mind uploading your `package.json` as well ? Thx

Comment: Just added it above

Comment: Could it be related to `babel-preset-env`. Seeing that the error happens at `module.exports` maybe it is related. Try setting the `module` option to false (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules). You should also probably `exclude` dependency files from babel transpilation.

Comment: setting module to false does not work. regenerator-runtime throws this error on core-js import "core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable";                                                                                       SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Just as an attempt to narrow down the search, try setting the targets to `"browsers": ["last 2 versions"]` (I never built for IE11, maybe it is related?).

If that doesn't help - it has to be one of the plugins not playing nice with `preset-env`. Maybe you should open an issue on babel's github, if nothing helps.

Comment: I tried setting the browsers to "last 2 versions" but that doesnt help either. The funny thing is that the compiles and runs perfectly using babel-loader and webpack but tests don't run with jest. What else can I do to debug?

Comment: I have the same problem, did u figure out what it is?